# How to change UIButton label programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

When I first run my app, I retrieve a number from my server and display it for my UIButton label. Think of this as a notification number displayed on a red UIButton.

When I remove a notification within the app, I want my UIButton label decrement by 1. I am able to get the decremented number from the server after I delete a notification, but I can't display this new number on the UIButton. The button always displays the number when the app is first fired.

I call `makeButtonView()` method after I remove a notification to update the UIButton

```
func makeButtonView(){
    var button = makeButton()
    view.addSubView(button)

    button.tag = 2
    if (view.viewWithTag(2) != nil) {
        view.viewWithTag(2)?.removeFromSuperview()
        var updatedButton = makeButton()
        view.addSubview(updatedButton)
    }else{
        println("No button found with tag 2")
    }


}

func makeButton() -> UIButton{
 let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 5, 60, 40))
 button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "redBubbleButton"), forState: .Normal)
    API.getNotificationCount(userID) {
        data, error in

        button.setTitle("\(data)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
    button.addTarget(self, action: "targetController:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return button

}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of adding/removing the button from the view and create the button twice. Anyway what updatedNotificationButton is?

        var updatedButton = makeButton()
        view.addSubview(updatedNotificationButton)

Comment: I did this because the label doesn't reset to the new number. It's always the same number. I thought I needed to kill the button and recreate it, but that didn't help either. I fixed the code you pointed out.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code for Swift 4 or 5

```
button.setTitle("Click Me", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

I need more information to give you a proper code. But this approach should work:

```
lazy var button : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 5, 60, 40))
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "redBubbleButton"), forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "targetController:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return button
    }()

func makeButtonView(){
    // This should be called just once!!
    // Likely you should call this method from viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func updateButton(){
    API.getNotificationCount(userID) {
        data, error in
        // be sure this is call in the main thread!!
        button.setTitle("\(data)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. It just works as it was before. The button label number didn't decrement. But I can see the number returned from the server after I delete a notification.

Comment: Just so you know I delete the notification in a different page. Then I close the notification page. The button and notifications are not on the same storyboard.

Comment: Storyboard? Sorry, but that doesn't make any sense. Are you creating your button using storyboard or programatically?

Comment: Red notifications button and Notifications view--where I delete a notification-- are two different parts of the same app. I tap on notifications button when I run the app frst, notifications view comes up. I delete a notification, close the page and I see the red button label didn't change.

Comment: Yes, I am creating the button programatically. Sorry, I should have said storyboard, they are not on the same view.

Comment: Where updateButton() is called? Could you please show the code of getNotificationCount(userId)? Are you sure data has the updated valued?

Comment: `func updateButton(){
        API.getNotificationCount(userID) {
            data, error in
 /*I see data is  data is the right number*/
            self.button.setTitle("\(data)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84223/discussion-between-agy-and-kleinfeltersville).

Answer (score 1):

There have been some updates since Swift 4. This works for me:

self.button.setTitle("Button Title", for: UIControl.State.init(rawValue: 0))

Replace button with your IBOutlet name. You can also use a variable or array in place of the quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple ...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.setTitle("hello world", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

I believe if you set the state to normal, the value will propagate by default to other states so long as you haven't explicitly set a title for those states.

Said differently, if you set it for normal, it should also display this title when the button enters additional states

```
UIControlState.allZeros
UIControlState.Application
UIControlState.Disabled
UIControlState.Highlighted
UIControlState.Reserved
UIControlState.Selected
```

Lastly, here's [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:) in case you have other questions.

Comment: I am creating the button programmatically, why do I need an outlet for that? Button doesn't reset the title.

Comment: By the way, I don't see how your code is different than mine when setting the title.

Answer (score 0):

Since your API call should be running on a background thread you need to dispatch your UI update back to the main thread like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      button.setTitle(“new value”, forState: .normal)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the title, just a simple redraw of the button will do:

```
button.setNeedsDisplay();
```